# A view without an action, how?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, yii

I have some static views in my Yii application.
It seems to me pointless to write an empty action for that view (I do need the layout though, as some widgets there are dynamic, like the one showing user logged it/logged out etc).
How is it done, if at all possible?

Comment: MVC implies that each action is processed with one particular controller. And only controller knows about view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller you can define a "page" action in the actions method of CController -- from the documentation:

```
page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
```

see: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/22/how-to-display-static-pages-in-yii/

(If you used yiic to create a webapp it's probably already in your controller. Also note that if you are using friendly urls, you can access pages via `/site/page/view/pagename` or further customize the pattern via the urlManager.)